# How to test whether a component is dynamically loaded in angular 7 karma tests?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have made a component in which I am dynamically loading another component which is working fine on `ng serve`. Below is the code for dynamically loading the component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, Type, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { AddComponentDirective } from '../add-component.directive';
import { DynamicComponent } from '../dynamic/dynamic.component';
import { ComponentData } from '../component-data';
import { ComponentItem } from '../component-item';

  export class DynamicLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild (AddComponentDirective) adhost : AddComponentDirective;

      constructor(private componentFactoryResolver : ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.loadComponent(DynamicComponent,message,this.adhost);
      }

      loadComponent(comp, message, host){
          let adItem = new ComponentItem(comp,{msg: message});
          let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
          let viewContainerRef = host.viewContainer;
          let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      (<ComponentData>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
    }
 }
```

But while testing it with angular karma test, we are facing type error i.e.

> TypeError: this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory is not a function

Below is the **spec.ts** file how I am testing it.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed ,getTestBed,inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ComponentFactoryResolver,ViewChild,DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
import { AddComponentDirective } from '../add-component.directive';
import { DynamicComponent } from '../dynamic/dynamic.component';
import { DynamicLoaderComponent } from './dynamic-loader.component';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";
import { ComponentData } from "../component-data";

describe('DynamicLoaderComponent', () => {
  let component: DynamicLoaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DynamicLoaderComponent>;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let componentFactoryResolver : ComponentFactoryResolver ;
  let debugElement: DebugElement

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DynamicLoaderComponent,AddComponentDirective ,DynamicComponent],
      providers:[DynamicLoaderComponent,ComponentFactoryResolver]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [DynamicComponent]
      }
    });

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DynamicLoaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentFactoryResolver =  fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ComponentFactoryResolver);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });  

  it('should create the DynamicLoaderComponent',inject([DynamicLoaderComponent], (component : DynamicLoaderComponent) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

[image: An image of the error of the test file on the browser is attached. Click to view]

Can you help me solve this issue so that I can proceed further in the testing of dynamic components?

Answer (score 10):

There are several changes you need to make to fix those errors:

1) Remove `providers` from TestBed configuration

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ DynamicLoaderComponent,AddComponentDirective ,DynamicComponent],
  providers:[DynamicLoaderComponent,ComponentFactoryResolver] <== remove this line
})
```

2) You do not need to get your component from DI,

so replace

```
it('should create the DynamicLoaderComponent', inject([DynamicLoaderComponent], (component : DynamicLoaderComponent) => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

with:

```
it('should create the DynamicLoaderComponent', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

3) `compileComponents()` call is only needed if you run tests in a non-CLI environment.

From [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-async-beforeeach)

> Calling compileComponents() closes the current TestBed instance to
>   further configuration. You cannot call any more TestBed configuration
>   methods, not configureTestingModule() nor any of the override...
>   methods. The TestBed throws an error if you try.

That means that your `TestBed.overrideModule` call won't have any effect and `DynamicComponent`'s factory won't be found.

So remove `.compileComponents();`

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ DynamicLoaderComponent,AddComponentDirective ,DynamicComponent],
  providers:[DynamicLoaderComponent,ComponentFactoryResolver]
})
.compileComponents(); <==== remove this
```

If you're on non-angular-cli environment then you can call it after overriding module:

```
TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [DynamicComponent]
  }
});

TestBed.compileComponents(); <== this line
```

---

After all changes I've written above, the test should be executed without any errors.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8XVmZERqlfd4QsJxSTb5?p=preview)**

Comment: When i removed the providers from TestBed configurations then it throws an error  `no providers for the DynamicLoaderComponent`

Comment: @Samir Ahmad Please follow all steps I provided. I also added plunker example

Comment: That `overrideModule` piece is the part that I missed.

Comment: Your plunker tests fail